# Get the homebrew install prefix of a formula in another Homebrew formula

Tags: homebrew

I'm packaging the Homebrew formula for a C++20 software that cannot compile with the default Apple `clang` (at least not on Monterey, I still have to test on Ventura), so I need to compile it using the `clang` provided by the Homebrew `llvm` formula, which ships LLVM version 14.

To compile it I need to set some environment variables before running CMake. This is how I do it in `bash`:

```
export CC=$(brew --prefix llvm)/bin/clang
export CXX=$(brew --prefix llvm)/bin/clang++
export LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix llvm)/lib -Wl,-rpath,$(brew --prefix llvm)/lib"
export CXXFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix llvm)/include"
```

I know in the `def install` block of the formula I can set environment variables with `ENV["variable"] = "value"`, but the values as you can see depend on the prefix install of the `llvm` formula.

In the `def install` block of my formula, how can I construct those strings that depends on the install prefix of the `llvm` formula? Please note that I'm not at all familiar with Ruby's syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like below (assuming you have `depends_on "llvm"`)

```
export CC=Formula["llvm"].opt_bin/clang
export CXX=Formula["llvm"].opt_bin/clang++
export LDFLAGS="-LFormula["llvm"].opt_lib -Wl,-rpath,Formula["llvm"].opt_lib"
export CXXFLAGS="-IFormula["llvm"].opt_include"
```

You can see the code definitions for `opt_*` in [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb#L1013-L1068)

[update]

In terms of using those environments inside the `formula`, it would be like this:

```
  def install
    ENV["CC"]=Formula["llvm"].opt_bin/"clang"
    ENV["CXX"]=Formula["llvm"].opt_bin/"clang++"
    ENV["LDFLAGS"]="-L#{Formula["llvm"].opt_lib} -Wl,-rpath,#{Formula["llvm"].opt_lib}"
    ENV["CXXFLAGS"]="-I#{Formula["llvm"].opt_include}"
    ...
  end
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems what I needed. But sorry for the naive question: are these Ruby statements to put in the `def install` block?

Comment: I have updated the answer by including the DSL syntax of defining the environment variables.